# Query to compare multiple records for a person

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a query to find all records that have the value `C` in the `Type` column `AND` it is not the latest date.  For example, in `Table1` the value `C` should be the latest date, but John Smith also had type `B` and `A` that come after `2014-02-01`.  Joana and Brian would both not appear in the results.

Person:

```
FirstName    LastName    DOB           Type    Date
John         Smith       01/01/1992    C       2014-02-01
John         Smith       01/01/1992    B       2014-05-01
John         Smith       01/01/1992    A       2014-04-01
Joana        Doe         05/14/1971    A       2014-07-01
Joana        Doe         05/14/1971    C       2014-09-01
Brian        Holden      12/01/1992    A       2014-08-01
```

I am at a total loss on what to even do.  Here is what I was thinking:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DOB
FROM Table1
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, DOB
HAVING COUNT(LastName) > 1 AND Type='C'
```

Any tips on what I can try would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
select firstname, lastname, dob from table1 left join
(select max(date) as maxdate from table1) as m on table1.date=m.maxdate
where table1.Type='C' and m.maxdate is null;
```

The left join with where clause requiring null in second table's join field is a pattern that finds all in first table that do not have, in this case, the maximum date.

Comment: This selects the max date from the table.  I would need to select the max date for each person.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, dob order by date desc) as seqnum
      from person
      where type = 'C'
     ) p
where seqnum > 1;
```

EDIT:

I misread the question, I think.  You want records that come after the latest `C` date.  The idea is similar, using `max()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             max(case when type = 'C' then date end) over (partition by firstname, lastname, dob) as maxcdate
      from person
      where type = 'C'
     ) p
where date > maxcdate and type <> 'C';
```

Comment: This just pulls the records where `C` is the latest date?  I need it to pull it when there are records after the date for `C`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to check for another row with a greater date

```
select FirstName, LastName, DOB
from Table1 t1
where Type = 'C'
and exists (
    select 1 from Table1 t2
    where t2.FirstName = t1.FirstName
    and t2.LastName = t1.LastName
    and t2.DOB = t1.DOB
    and t2.Date > t1.Date
)
```

Or you could modify your original group by query

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DOB
FROM Table1
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, DOB
HAVING MAX(Date) > MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN Date END)
```